# Does 'Questions that may already have your answer' analyse anything other than the title?

Tags: support, similar-questions

Does this feature analyse / perform some kind of regular expression pattern matching on the title only OR does it also look at data within the body of the question or post and the data of any associated approved answers?

Comment: It should at least include the tags, imo.

Answer (score 7):

## Nope! Just the title.

That's (partly) why you're encouraged to a Google search for your problem beforehand.

Comment: Google is THE search engine for every other web site, especially SO

Comment: I think it analyzes the body of the questions that it suggests, but only based on the title of the question that is being asked. For example, when I type `piece of C++ code that seems very peculiar. For some strange reason, sorting the data` as a title, it suggests [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11227809/4284627) even though the titles don't have any words in common (but the title I typed is copy-pasted from the first paragraph of the body of the question).

Answer (score 3):

It only analyzes the title of the question being asked, but also analyzes the body of the questions that it suggests.

I found this out by testing. I copy-pasted `piece of C++ code that seems very peculiar. For some strange reason, sorting the data` from the first paragraph of [Why is it faster to process a sorted array than an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11227809/4284627), and it suggests that question even though the title I entered doesn't have any word in common with the title that question:

[image]

This proves that it also analyzes the body of the questions that it suggests (but it seems like the title has a higher priority since that question is only the third suggestion).

On the other hand, it only analyzes the title of the question that is being asked. I tested this on the same question and entered the title of that question in the body of my question and a junk title as the title, and it didn't suggest that question:

[image]

Even when scrolling down in the "Questions that may already have your answer" list, that question isn't there. And even when copy-pasting the body of that question into the body of my question, it doesn't suggest that question:

[image]