# Questions that definitely do not have the answer to my question

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, similar-questions

I tried to ask the following question:

> [image: A question tagged with JavaScript]

The question is tagged with [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript). And I get various candidates, which "may" already have the answer. But none of the candidates even match the programming language. The six top suggestions are obviously completely irrelevant.

I would call it a bug, if the tags are not correctly compared.

Comment: What if a question is tagged with 2 languages (font / back-end)? What language should be used for the comparison?

Comment: @Cerbrus: Both, I would guess. Bringing in results from completely unrelated languages doesn't seem helpful.

Comment: @user000001: Assuming the issue is in _both_ tags. So, now it can only suggest questions that have the exact same tags. That's rather counter-productive.

Comment: @Cerbrus: I meant results in any of the two languages. Not to have the exact combination of tags.

Comment: It is just not very sophisticated, also obvious from the Related list to the right of a question.  One design choice that does not help much is that the tags are at the bottom, so entered last.  Afaik the machine only looks at the Title.  There are many, many possible wins from improving this page.  It has been talked about for the past 4 years but nothing was done.  I suspect there is nobody around anymore that still knows the code or dares touch it after umpteen perf tweaks.

Comment: I too thought the suggestions only come from the title.. Ceving, if you think SO's NLP is crap and should be improved, why not get a job with them to do it?

Comment: @CaiusJard They have no office [here](https://www.openstreetmap.de/karte.html?zoom=15&lat=51.47466&lon=6.94937&layers=B000TT).

Comment: The answer to the question in question is "No". Not unless you're comparing references to the same object. to different node objects can reference the same node while being different objects, this would evaluate to false. If you want to compare nodes, use [`Node#isSameNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/isSameNode)

Comment: Did you just answer an SO question in a meta comment ? How unusual... and funny... i guess.

Comment: meh... most of the time when I type out a question the suggestions are related. If you change your prompt to `can you` instead of `is it safe` it seems to give more relevant suggestions, so maybe it's just putting too much weight on specific words or the start of the sentence. If none of the suggestions are relevant that just means your question is a good one to post, right?

Comment: Tangential, but the 'related' questions seem heavily biased towards votes, regardless of actual relation. If I had a dollar for every time I saw the "why does loop run faster on sorted array" question...

Comment: Just to confirm what commenters have speculated, it seems that [it only analyses the title](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360061/does-questions-that-may-already-have-your-answer-analyse-anything-other-than-t)

Comment: Duplicate on Meta SE - [Let the duplicate questions finder consider tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137981)

Comment: @CaiusJard If the answer to every bug in a program was to get a job with that company and fix it yourself you'd be forever changing jobs.

Comment: Limiting a search by the tags is already possible with the search box... so the appropriate process is to perform an explicit search filtered by tags _before even considering a new question_.  The suggestions are listed as a last-effort attempt to help avoid duplicate questions. This meta question implies that the system should assume that 1) the selected tags are definitely the most appropriate tags, 2) the question is so specific that no useful answers exists outside the very narrow context of the tags.  That might be true _sometimes_, but not generally.

Comment: @Tas No, it also analyzes the body of the questions it suggests. I just posted [an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/360425/4284627) to the question you linked to explaining that that's the case and how I found that out.

Answer (score 8):

We've made some changes to how the search works here due to performance reasons...but it turns out they greatly increased relevancy as well, specifically due to quoted strings being inadvertently excluded before. There are other reasons it's better (and faster) due to the filter and boosting changes, but the moral of the story is: results are more relevant now (at least on average) and we saw a drastic uptick in usage after the change. Which, given we did this for performance, was a very nice surprise. Here's what the same title returns today:

[image: title search]

Comment: Does that mean tags *are* considered? I see an `Obj-C` question at the bottom, surely that shouldn't come up when you search for a `javascript` Q&A?

Comment: They are considered and weighted, but they are not required to match. There are a lot of similar tags or people forgetting to tag a thing, and when entering a title there may be (and often are) no tags yet. When reasoning about a tag match - if we required them to match, we'd be removing the relevant results *most* of the time. So it's just a strong suggestion that they match.

Comment: Was this changed again in the [Duplicate questions display experiment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/384710)? The [top voted answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384710/duplicate-questions-display-experiment/384716#384716) in that thread asks to use tags for this purpose.